# Subdomains as a part of the one site

Tags: google-search-console, subdomain, xml-sitemap

Let's say that the site consists of some pages like:

```
some_product.example.com
some_service.example.com
another_product.example.com
...so on
```

Can I work with such a site using Google Webmasters Tools, Sitemaps as with normal sites made within one domain?

Answer (score 1):

You can have one sitemap that includes all your verified sites. Check [Sitemaps for multiple sites on Google Webmasters Tools](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/75712?hl=en&topic=8476&ctx=topic).

If you want to have complete independence from each subdomain, then you have to have one sitemap per subdomain. Then, if you don't want to verify each subdomain, or even if you do, you can have the sitemap on the robots.txt.

Also, considering what is stated at [sitemaps.org - Where do I place my Sitemap?](http://www.sitemaps.org/faq.html#faq_sitemap_location), you can see that each sitemap has to be on each subdomain.

Comment: That can be useful if the amount of subdomains not very big. But I'd like to have automatic approach...
So can I state that all subdomains are considered by GWT as different unless they are verified in the GWT panel? And can I sate that sitemap can not refer to the pages placed on another subdomain?

Comment: yes. That's exactly how that works. Each subdomain may behave as a separate site if not verified by you or on the same account as the one that submits the sitemap. If you operate on that premise, then you need one sitemap per subdomain/site.